# How to Allow a "/" character after base url in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

After updating the PHP version symfony application does not work anymore with double slash.

**PHP 7.0 (is Working)**

`https://baseUrl//api/users`

**PHP 7.1 (it does not work)**

`https://baseUrl//api/users`

Unfortunately, our store app use for api request a double slash. 
We use api-platform for our api endpoints.

We tried to fix it with htacces but during forwarding the app loses the auth header.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:ps}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=307]
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to try the following hack:

```
# config/routes/api_platform.yaml

api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /{api}
    requirements:
       api: \/{0,1}api$
    defaults:
       api: /api
```

Comment: Thank you, it now works with double slash, but unfortunately not with a slash. Is it possible to define several rules or hacks? if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Thanks, it works but same api endpoint now returns different data :(

Comment: @HüseyinAkturan can you provide an example of your current problem? but first check   updated answer and tell if it solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks better with the last changes on local. I will check later on the server.